# Is using arr.push causing my program to crash?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello you wonderful people of the stackoverflow community. I'm stuck on a HW problem that I hope you can help me with.

```
// 5. Write the code that would make this test pass.

// describe("multTwo", () => {
//     test ("returns an array with all the numbers multiplied by two", () => {
//         expect(multTwo([3, 4, 5])).toEqual([6, 8, 10])
//         expect(multTwo([23, -9, 0])).toEqual([46, -18, 0])
//         expect(multTwo([4.5, -4.5, 12])).toEqual([9, -9, 24])
//     })
// })

let friendlyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
let newArr = []
const multTwo = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  arr.push(newArr[i] *2 )

  return arr;
};
console.log(multTwo(friendlyArray))
```

I'm trying to pass an array into a new one in which all of the numbers in the previous array have been multiplied by two.

When I run the program (using node on AWS) my environment runs out of memory and it kills all the processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you push to the array, its length increases. So if the original length was 5, after one iteration, the new length is 6. After the second iteration, the new length is 7. So

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

will loop forever.

Use `.map` instead, it's the most appropriate method for transforming one array into another, based on a callback function that runs on each element:

```js
const multTwo = arr => arr.map(num => num * 2);
let friendlyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(multTwo(friendlyArray))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning about .map and .filter so this answer helps me understand them better as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you push the value to the array the length increases. You are looping the array and pushing the value to it which causes the length to increase. After one element is pushed to Arr its increases so i initial length of 5 will become 6 and loops exit condition is never satisfied. Hence it will loop forever. 
`newArr[i] *2` will be undefined. Your function will return an array of infinite undefined.
Instead of pushing the value to Arr push the value to the newArr and return newArr.

```
let friendlyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
let newArr = []
const multTwo = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  newArr.push(arr[i] *2 )
  return newArr;
};
console.log(multTwo(friendlyArray))
```

Or you can reduce the number of code lines using map

```
let friendlyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
const multTwo = (arr) => (arr.map(el => el * 2))
console.log(multTwo(friendlyArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you intended to *read* from `arr`, the input parameter, and *push* to `newArr`. But you just swapped them. So this would make more sense:

```
for (...)
newArr.push(arr[i] *2 )

return newArr;
```

In general `map` is a good native alternative to what you're doing. It also doesn't rely on an array initialized outside the function scope. With the above correction your function would not be very reusable as it would just continually append to a persistent array `newArr`